# Bind exchange to exchange through Spring cloud stream with rabbitmq binder

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I'm looking for a way to bind a RabbitMQ exchange to another through Spring cloud stream.  I know I can bind a queue to an exchange by setting the `producer.requiredGroups` property:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.foo.producer.requiredGroups=queueA queueB
```

Which property can I use to create an exchange-to-exchange binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a required group, add `@Bean`s for the two exhanges and a `@Bean` for the binding.

See the [Spring AMQP documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/#broker-configuration).

```
@Bean
public TopicExchange destinatioExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("myDest");
}

@Bean
public DirectExchange boundExchange() {
    return new DirectExchange("bound");
}

@Bean
public Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder
            .bind(boundExchange())
            .to(destinatioExchange())
            .with("myRoutingKey");
}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=myDest
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.routing-key-expression='myRoutingKey'
```